# Acf plugin's value not getting with the_field in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, widget, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

[image]

I want to display acf value with using short code, i have craeted function in function.php file, and added this short code in widget sidebar, but it not returning value.In image filed i set image return value to image url but it not works.

1) The code i have written in function.php file

```
function myfunction() { 
?>

    <img src="<?php the_field('pop_img'); ?>" alt="no image" />

    <p><?php the_field('pop_date'); ?></p>

    <p><?php the_field('pop_btn_text'); ?></p>

<?php }
add_shortcode('display_popup','myfunction');
```

2) Output i am getting in widget is only

```
 "no image"
```

3) while displaying value with post id it returns something like this

```
code: 
<?php 
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r( get_fields(8647) );
        echo '</pre>';
        // die; 
    ?>

Output:
Array
(
    [] => 
    [pop_img] => http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/josh-woodward-gravity-mp3-image.jpg
    [pop_date] => 20171105
    [pop_btn_text] => dsdfdscfvdsvdv
)
```

Comment: what is your main Custom filed name of 3 field?

Comment: Main field group name is "Popup Group"

Comment: please share ACF your screenshot

Comment: Added to top of question

Comment: Are you in the loop? Have you tried `the_field('pop_img', 8647)`?

Comment: No, not in loop, i have tried this code, it display perfect output, but it is not correct way
    <img src="<?php the_field('pop_img','8647'); ?>" alt="no image" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**get ACF Value by using get_field () function**

```
 <?php 
    function myfunction() { 
       $popup_field_array= get_fields(8647);
        //$pop_img_path = get_field('pop_img', get_the_ID());
        $pop_img_path = $popup_field_array['pop_img'];
        $pop_date = $popup_field_array['pop_date'];
        $pop_btn_text = $popup_field_array['pop_btn_text'];
        if($pop_img_path != "")
        {
            ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $pop_img_path; ?>" alt="no image" />
            <?php
        }
    ?>
       <?php /*?> <p><?php echo get_field('pop_date', get_the_ID()); ?></p>
        <p><?php echo get_field('pop_btn_text',get_the_ID()); ?></p><?php */?>
         <p><?php echo $pop_date; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $pop_btn_text; ?></p>
    <?php 
    }
    add_shortcode('display_popup','myfunction');
?>
```

Comment: It returns complete blank, for image i had already choose return value to image url, and for pop_date, pop_btn_text it returns blank.

Comment: ok. please print_r($pop_img_array); and give me screen shot of out put. please check updated answer.

Comment: i did, it not display any content, it only display like this <pre></pre>

Comment: now please check update answer. also check your uploaded img?

Comment: Tryed your code, nothing display, and i have already cheaked with something like this, this give me exact output, that's means image uploaded successfully.                                                                       <img src="<?php the_field('pop_img','8647'); ?>" alt="no image" />

    <p><?php echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime(get_field('pop_date','8647'))); ?></p>
                
    <p><?php the_field('pop_btn_text','8647'); ?></p>

Comment: try this code. as per your output i updated my code.  $popup_field_array= get_fields(8647) );
        //$pop_img_path = get_field('pop_img', get_the_ID());
        $pop_img_path = $popup_field_array['pop_img'];

Comment: Yes it works, but for other post-id do i need to update code every time?

Comment: you can get id by using get_the_ID(); this function

Comment: you are wolcome :)